# Isight Camera + OpenCV + VMWARE

Tags: windows, opencv, vmware-fusion, isight

I'm running VMWARE on OS X to run Windows 7, and Visual Studio 2010.  I'm using OpenCV to do some image and video processing software.  I want to try and start doing processing to real time video.

I'm running the code from: [Real Time Canny](http://r3dux.org/2010/11/how-to-perform-real-time-opencv-edge-detection-o-a-webcam-stream/)

I change the input parameter of cvCaptureFromCAM to -1, since the only camera I have is the Isight(drivers are installed).  When the application runs I get nothing but a gray screen.  Does anyone know how to make the Isight camera work in this situation?

Setup:
VMWARE Fusion: 4.0.2
OS: Windows 7
OpenCV: 2.3

Comment: What standard output do you get?  Does the camera work outside of vmware (it may be possible to get OpenCV to run directly on top of OS/X)?

Comment: Yes, the iSight camera will work directly on top of OS/X.  This website shows compatible cameras : [link](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/OS)

Comment: It doesn't show compatibility for the iSight camera in the Windows environment, but I've seen some website that hint to the fact that this has been done, but I've tried some of the suggestions and they haven't worked yet.

The reason I have to use Windows is because I'm in a masters program and the teacher wants everyone to use Windows and Visual Studio(which is weird to me in an academic environment).

Comment: What standard output do you get?

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what you mean by standard output.  The application turns on the camera(the iSight's green light does turn on), but the named window that should be showing the feed from the webcam shows nothing, just a gray image.

Comment: Standard output is what is printed to the console (command-line).  For example, all those lines starting with `cout << string` print `string` to the console.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot about that console(I've been trying a whole bunch of things, and this website was just an example that was easy to put on here, so I forgot).  
"ERROR: SampleCB() - buffer sizes do not match" keeps repeating in the console.

Comment: Errors like that are important.  Google around for it -- it looks like a driver problem.  Failing that, you may also want to consider dual-booting Windows on your machine.  Good luck.